# system("tar xzf DirName/tarFile.tar DirNameInsideTar/FileName") in perl fails and returns -1

Tags: linux, perl, return, tar, exit-code

What does tar exit code of -1 means? I am using the command

```
system("tar xzf DirName/tarFile.tar DirNameInsideTar/FileName")
```

to untar from perl script. I am trying to untar around 1000  tar files but randomly after untarring sometimes 100 or sometimes 500 tar files the system command fails and returns -1. I checked both the memory usage of the code and disk space available and both seems fine. Does anyone know what the error could be?

Comment: It should print an error message on standard error when it gets an error.

Comment: There's no way for us to know what it could be, there are many possible reasons for an error.

Comment: It doesn't. I am even using --verbose but it doesn't give an error message

Comment: What happens if you try the exact same `tar` command by hand?

Comment: `tar`'s `z` option tells it to use `gzip`, but the `.tar` suffix implies that it's an uncompressed tar file.

Comment: When I use the same command by hand it untars the file properly. Sorry about that it is .tar.gz

Comment: What do you mean by _"tar exit code of -1"_?  The code you show will not give you the exit code of `tar`.  If `system` returns anything other than a `0` that _does not_ tell you a thing about how `tar` did, it only tells you that the command itself didn't run fine. Can you show us all relevant code?

Comment: @zdim: On a POSIX system, the value returned by `system()` is `-1` if something went wrong with `system` itself (for example if `fork()` failed); otherwise the value includes the exit status of the invoked process. Pranav: Your code shows the result of `system()` being discarded. Are you actually printing the value returned by the `system()` function? And is it actually returning `-1`?

Comment: @KeithThompson  Yes, that was my point.  The shown code will not reveal anything about what `tar` did.  If the OP actually unpacks the `$?` they should show this. I am also concerned with how those multiple files are being iterrated, then with output file/dir naming, etc.

Comment: You could be running into a per-user process limit. Are you running multiple commands in parallel? That would explain why fork fails, which would return -1.

Answer (score 4):

When `system` returns `-1`, `$!` contains the error message.

```
system("tar xzf DirName/tarFile.tar DirNameInsideTar/FileName");

die("Can't execute command: $!\n")              if $? == -1;
die("Child killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("Child exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n")  if $? >> 8;
```

(The value returned by `system` is also available as `$?`.)